# Excel VBA Progress Bar Display Macro Progress based on Active Worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, progress-bar

I am an apprentice software developer in my third week at the company and they've decided to start me off with excel macro's and VBA. It's been a nice challenge so far, and I'm learning more and more about reading code
My current task is understanding an excel splitter the company uses to bill their clients. I have manged to understand the code, manipulate it in certain ways, and even add further clients and and companies.

They are now asking me to make some optimizations to the code and to try make it run faster. 
My idea is to turn off screen updates and all that and to try and display a progress bar for the macro. I had first hoped to run the progress bar based on the different sub's/functions but that doesn't seem to be too easy.

**So**: I was hoping one of you could please assist/advise me on how I could make the progress bar run based on the amount of active sheets, as each time the splitter finishes with a client, it creates a new sheet.

**Here is the code for the first company:**

```
'Calling the functions
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    UserForm1.Show

    code

    Dim lastrow As Long

        lastrow = Sheets("Koh").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row

    For i = 2 To lastrow
        Call GenericFindAndSplit(Sheets("Koh").Range("A" & i), Sheets("Koh").Range("B" & i), Sheets("Koh").Range("C" & i))
    Next i

End Sub

Function GenericFindAndSplit(SheetName As String, LowExt As Integer, HighExt As Integer)

    Dim count As Integer
        count = 2

'Add a new sheet to the workbook
'Worksheet name is obtained from the "Koh" tab

    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.count)).Name = SheetName

'Copy first row of the Data sheet and paste to the newly created sheet
    Sheets("Data-KM").Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy
    Sheets(SheetName).Rows(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

'Search the Data sheet for the selected extensions and paste them on the newly created sheet
    For r = Sheets("Data-KM").UsedRange.Rows.count To 1 Step -1
        If Sheets("Data-KM").Cells(r, "L") >= LowExt And Sheets("Data-KM").Cells(r, "L") <= HighExt Then
                Sheets("Data-KM").Rows(r).EntireRow.Copy
                Sheets(SheetName).Range("A" & count).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next

End Function

Sub ExportSheetsToCSV()

'If Dir("C:\Temp\", vbDirectory) = "" Then

    'Kill ("C:\Temp\") & "*.*"

'End If

Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xcsvFile As String

    For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    'Loop for each worksheet on the workbook

        If xWs.Name <> "Sheet1" And xWs.Name <> "Data-KM" And xWs.Name <> "Koh" Then
            xWs.Copy
            'Copy worksheet
            xcsvFile = "GlobalCDR_" & ActiveSheet.Name & ".csv"
            'Copies files into the C Drive under Temp
                Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Temp\" & xcsvFile, FileFormat:=xlCSV
                ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
        End If
    Next

'Automatically saves and closes workbook
ThisWorkbook.Saved = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'Application.Quit
End Sub
```

**The following is my attempt at trying to code progress based on active sheets**

```
Sub code()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, pctCompl As Single

For i = 1 To 100
    For ActiveWorkbook = 1 To 7
        ActiveWorkbook.Value = j
    Next j
    pctCompl = i
    progress pctCompl
Next i

End Sub

Sub progress(pctCompl As Single)

UserForm1.Text.Caption = pctCompl & "% Completed"
UserForm1.Bar.Width = pctCompl * 2

DoEvents

End Sub
```

**And then finally this is my code for the UserForm I created:**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
code
End Sub
```

Any advice you could provide would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance, and thank you also for your previous contributions, they have been invaluable to me over this three week period :)

Comment: you cab either optimize the speed or create an illusion of progressbar. Both of them together doesn't happen. Not easily.

Comment: You'll get a lot more traction by actually improving the code. For example, you repeatedly call `Sheets("Data-KM")` in a loop. Add a `With` block. Hard code the sheet references of deterministic calls (like `Sheets("Data-KM")`). Use arrays instead of cell ranges. Stopping screen updating and displaying how slow it is in the progress bar doesn't strike me as a solution.

Comment: Custom progress bar = overhead = more execution time. It's probably better to look at actual optimizations. Some nice ones for the beginner are listed [here at Ozgrid](https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/SpeedingUpVBACode.htm)
Another big win will be to stop looping and look at ways to do copy-paste operations at once instead of line by line.